# What are the compcost operations using compged for my example strings

Tags: sas

Here is the code with strings I used but I am unable to understand why I am getting 90 score for the following. I only undertand that due to the truncation(letter R) I get a score of 10 but I am not able to understand how DRIVE with FRONT is giving 80. Not sure what operations it is doing and how I get this specific(DRIVE,FRONT) as 80?

```
DATA Compged_score;

 CALL  COMPCOST('SWAP=', 5, 'P=', 0, 'INS=', 10,'DEL=',10,'APPEND=',5);

 COMPGED_SCORE=COMPGED("DRIVER IS GOOD", "FRONT IS GOOD", 'iln');

 RUN;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `COMPGED` documentation states:

> **Definition of Generalized Edit Distance**
>
> Generalized edit distance is a generalization of Levenshtein edit
>   distance, which is a measure of dissimilarity between two strings. The
>   Levenshtein edit distance is the number of deletions, insertions, or
>   replacements of single characters that are required to transform
>   string-1 into string-2.
>
> **Computing the Generalized Edit Distance**
>
> The COMPGED function returns the generalized edit distance between
>   string-1 and string-2.  The generalized edit distance is the
>   **minimum-cost sequence** of operations for constructing string-1 from
>   string-2.

```
D R I V E R   I S   G O O D
F R O N T   I S   G O O D
```

Here is a 90 cost sequence of operations. Perhaps this is the sequence `COMPGED` chose from other least cost (90) scores.

```
10 INSERT R after T  FRONTR IS GOOD
10 DELETE F          RONTR IS GOOD
10 INSERT D          DRONTR IS GOOD
10 DELETE O          DRNTR IS GOOD
10 INSERT I          DRINTR IS GOOD
10 DELETE N          DRITR IS GOOD
10 INSERT V          DRIVTR IS GOOD
10 DELETE T          DRIVR IS GOOD
10 INSERT E          DRIVER IS GOOD
---
90 cost of operations
```

FRONT to DRIVE would be the same with out the initial INSERT, so 8 10-point operations is score of 80.  I don't know if there are any options that force the function to log the operations behind the score.